# trying to understand HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN combined flags:

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test1 (a int, b int);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (16777217, 131584);
VACUUM (DISABLE_PAGE_SKIPPING) test1;  -- set up FSM

SELECT t_ctid, t_infomask, t_infomask2, raw_flags, combined_flags
FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('test1', 0)),
     LATERAL heap_tuple_infomask_flags(t_infomask, t_infomask2);
```

return:

```
 t_ctid | t_infomask | t_infomask2 |                         raw_flags                         |   combined_flags
--------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------------
 (0,1)  |       2816 |           2 | {HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED,HEAP_XMIN_INVALID,HEAP_XMAX_INVALID} | {HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN}
 (0,2)  |       2304 |           2 | {HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED,HEAP_XMAX_INVALID}                   | {}
(2 rows)
```

select  ctid, xmin,xmax from test1;
returns:

```
 ctid  | xmin  | xmax
-------+-------+------
 (0,1) | 25626 |    0
 (0,2) | 25642 |    0
(2 rows)
```

reference:

```c
File: /home/jian/Desktop/pg_sources/main/postgres/src/include/access/htup_details.h
204: #define HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED        0x0100  /* t_xmin committed */
205: #define HEAP_XMIN_INVALID      0x0200  /* t_xmin invalid/aborted */
206: #define HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN       (HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED|HEAP_XMIN_INVALID)
```

try to understand this combined flags HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN as plain english:
for this specific table, at this moment, any tuple txid >= 25626 is visible to every session.
Is my understanding correct?
also not %100 sure what does HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED, HEAP_XMIN_INVALID mean in this context. source code comments is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example inserts only a single row, but your query shows two tuples, so the two don't match.

Anyway, `HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN` means that the tuple in unconditionally visible, and its `xmin` and `xmax` should be ignored. To avoid the need for an extra flag, the otherwise impossible combination `HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED | HEAP_XMIN_INVALID` was used to encode that state.